# passing a parameter to fillby(vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have problem passing a parameter to `fillby`

I made fill method call `FillByA` but there is problem!!

its said:

> “too many arguments to ‘public  override  Overloads function fillbyA(data Table as ContactsDataSet.recordsDataTable) as integer’

This is my code:

```
Public Class Adminlogin
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text.Trim = "" Or TextBox2.Text.Trim = "" Then
            MsgBox("you should complet ypur deails")
        Else

//error happen here !
            Me.AdminTableAdapter.FillByA(Me.UserDataSet1.Admin, Me.TextBox1.Text.Trim, Me.TextBox2.Text.Trim)

            If Me.UserDataSet1.user.Count > 0 Then
                Me.Close()
                Test.Show()
            Else
                MsgBox("Logon failure, user name or password are incorrect!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Ad_NameTextBox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        If IsNumeric(e.KeyChar.ToString()) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Letters only!")
            SendKeys.Send("{Backspace}")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Ad_NameTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Close()
        admincon.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Firstly, why is your method called `FillByA` in the first place? You are supposed to give that method a logical name that describes its purpose. For instance, if you add a `WHERE` clause to filter by the `Name` column then your method should be named `FillByName`.

Comment: That also leads onto your issue.  The parameters that the `FillBy` method has are generated directly from the parameters in the `WHERE` clause of your SQL code.  If you haven't written your SQL code with two parameters then passing two arguments to the method would be useless, even if it was possible. I suggest that you do a bit more reading on how to work with table adapters. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171905.aspx

Comment: oh i didn't know that!..okay i fixed but still its said

Comment: too many arguments to ‘public  override  Overloads function fillbyAd_Name(data Table as ContactsDataSet.recordsDataTable) as integer

Comment: See my second comment above and follow the link.